# What is the equivalent in SQLite of a MySQL statement, using a sub-select that refers a field alias

Tags: mysql, sqlite, subquery

The question looks more complicated than the problem itself. So here the example.
I have a "Test" table in **MySQL** with only one field: ObjectId INTEGER(10).
Values in the ObjectId field:

1

1

1

2

2

I execute the following statement in MySQL query browser:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ObjectId obid, (SELECT count(*) FROM Test WHERE ObjectId = obid) AS cnt FROM Test
```

The result is what I expect: in the example above, a number of 2 rows containing:

Column 1: the ObjectId value

Column 2: the number of times the respective ObjectId value appears in the column.

```
obid        cnt
1           3
2           2
```

Now I execute the same statement on an identical table (structure and data) created in a **SQLite** database. I get an error telling that "no such column: obid".

The above mentioned SELECT is quite convenient for my purpose. It would look a bit odd to be forced to replace it with a series of selects (like using a cursor). I am new to SQLite, so maybe I miss something. I've investigated a lot with zero results.

So, has anyone an idea if there is a similar, single SELECT statement, that would produce the same result on the SQLite database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the complicated way.  :)  [`GROUP BY`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) should get what you want.

```
SELECT ObjectID AS obid, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM Test
GROUP BY ObjectID
```

Comment: Thanks galador, you're absolutely right, it works and it's much simpler. I should reconsider my complicated way :)